# Variable might be assigned in loop?

Tags: java, while-loop, initialization, final

I don't know why the code is not compiling when `final` variable is initialized in loop and loop iterate only one time? Is Loop is somehow running more than one time and multiple assignments is done to variable `x`?

```
public static void main(String args[]) {

    int y;
    final int x;
    y=1;
    while(y<=1) {
        x=10;       //Compile time error; even loop iterate only once.
        y++;
    }
}
```

Comment: The variable has already been assigned 0 on declaration

Comment: The compiler isn't sentient, and isn't capable of knowing the loop only runs once. Why put it in a loop here at all?

Comment: sir, give me the reason if you know.

Comment: @LionardoDiCaprio The compiler almost certainly constructs a [directed acyclic graph](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Directed_acyclic_graph) (DAG) and detects that there is a potential cycle in the assignment statement. Unfortunately, I'm not certain if I can simplify that in a comment. It's actually a rather complex topic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The compiler does not care how many times the code in the loop will be executed at run time.  To prevent re-assignments that *might* happen, it is not allowed to assign final variables in a loop.

Answer (score 3):

Remove the keyword `final`. You cannot assign a value to the variable which is `final` over again and again. You can not initialize the `final` value in the `for` or `while` loop defined outside of the scope loop. Even the loop is called once, the compiler doesn not know in advance how many times the cycle would be called.

Comment: "it happens because it's not know in advance how many times the cycle will be called" what this means?

Comment: The compiler doesn't know how many times the cycle will be called in advance. If it knows that just once, then it should work theoretically - however it never gets this information, thus you have to initialize out of any loop. The `final` requires the initialization just once - it's a contradiction with a cycle with an unknown number of loops.

Answer (score 1):

In java, a final variable is a constant so you can not change its value. In your code above, x is final variable and I see that you are trying to change value of x. So you got compiler time error.

Answer (score 0):

when you have instance variable declared

```
final int x;
```

x is assigned to 0.
and **final** tag won't allow it to be changed.

```
while(y<=1) {
    x=10;       //Compile time error; even loop iterate only once.
y++;
}
```

inside while loop, you assign x to 10 which disobey the **final** rule.